# Why is pdfpages' addtotoc option giving me «Illegal parameter number in definition of \AM@temp» error message?

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, pdfpages

I am trying to add a few pdf pages in my LaTeX file and have them shown in the table of contents. My file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Itinerário de Formação, Aperfeiçoamento e Titulação}

blah.

\includepdf[pages={1-3},landscape=true,addtotoc{1,section,1,{Pontuação para RSC I},app1}]{form-pontos.pdf}

\end{document}
```

And when compiled with pdflatex it gives me the following error message:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \AM@temp.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Thanks.

P.S. BTW, without the addtotoc option, the includepdf macro works as intended and the pages are included in the document.

Comment: There is an equal sign missing after addtotoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 addtotoc={1,section,1,{Pontuação para RSC I},app1}
```